# Is it possible to compare user input?

Tags: ruby

```
print "Enter your age in Numbers:"
user_input = gets.chomp
if user_input > 21 && user_input < 30
  puts "XYZ"
elsif user_input > 31 && user_input < 40
  puts "YZX"
elsif user_input > 40
  puts "ZXY"
else
  puts "Golden Age!"
end
```

Comment: Don't write the question in the title, write it in the text. Even from the title, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `gets.chomp` returns a string

You can convert it to integer by using `String#to_i`: `gets.chomp.to_i`

---

You can further improve the readability of your code by using `between?`:

```
print "Enter your age in Numbers:"
number = gets.chomp.to_i
if number.between?(22, 29)
  puts "XYZ"
elsif number.between?(32, 39)
  puts "YZX"
elsif number > 40
  puts "ZXY"
else
  puts "Golden Age!"
end
```

Or even better - a `case` statement:

```
print "Enter your age in Numbers:"
number = gets.chomp.to_i
case number
when (22...30)             then puts "XYZ"
when (32...40)             then puts "YXZ"
when (40..Float::INFINITY) then puts "ZXY"
else puts "Golden Age!"
end
```

---

**Note**: I made the ranges compatible with your original solution, but please note that there are some gaps in there (31 for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can compare objects on which `<=>` is defined properly, but you cannot compare a string object with a fixnum object. If you intended to compare as an integer, you need to convert the input to integer. Also, (assuming that you only get inputs that can be converted to integers), your condition is redundant. And you are probably using `&&` incorrectly. It can be written like this:

```
print "Enter your age in Numbers:"
user_input = gets.to_i
if user_input < 20 or [20, 21, 30, 31, 40].include?(user_input)
  puts "Golden Age!"
elsif user_input < 30
  puts "XYZ"
elsif user_input < 40
  puts "YZX"
else
  puts "ZXY"
end
```